# Application not responding upon receipt of data

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

I'm trying to fill `ListView` by components from database. When I open the page app freezes with error "Application is not responding". Logs have no exceptions.

ContentPage :

```
public PollsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getPolls();
        
    }

    public async Task getPolls()
    {
        Database.SmartYardDB db = new Database.SmartYardDB();
        if(db.getNotAnsweredPolls().Result != null)
            lvPolls.ItemsSource = (IList<Models.Tables.Polls>)db.getNotAnsweredPolls().Result;
    }
```

`getNotAnsweredPolls` from `Database` class:

```
public SQLiteAsyncConnection db;

        public async Task init()
        {
            if (db is not null)
            {
                return;
            }

            db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.Database.DatabasePath, Constants.Database.Flags);
            await db.CreateTableAsync<Models.Tables.Users>();
            await db.CreateTableAsync<Models.Tables.Messages>();
            await db.CreateTableAsync<Models.Tables.Polls>();
        }

public async Task<List<Models.Tables.Polls>> getNotAnsweredPolls()
        {
            await init();
            return await db.Table<Models.Tables.Polls>().Where(
                x => x.userAnswer != Constants.Database.POLLS_USERANSWER_NOTANSWERED &&
                x.status == Constants.Database.POLLS_STATUS_ACTIVE).ToListAsync();

        }
```

How I take the path to database:

```
public static string DatabasePath =>
        Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DB_NAME);
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: don't call `async` methods from the constructor.  You can use `OnAppearing` to do this instead

Answer (score 0):

Network and database work should be done in separate threads, while the UI is initialized and responsive. You should also make sure the user can cancel those at will, if you expect this work to take long time to finish.

Instead of frozen grayed-out screen, the user should see "Fetching data...", some activity indicator rotating, cancel/try again buttons, etc.

Your Page (View) is responsible for displaying user interface. Let it do its work. After that override Events (or even better - bind them to ViewModel) and deal with background work there.

Comment: of course I understand it, but now I am learning only, so I can't do it on practice, can u give me a hint, how I can to solve the problem?

Comment: If you are learning, just add button and bind command to it, that will initialize the database. What I do in my projects is exactly what I have told you: Some activity indicator rotating, label to indicate that it is doing some work, and when it is done - displaying the data. I use CommunityToolkit.MVVM for architecture, and CommunityToolkit.MAUI for assisting with behaviors, binding events to commands etc...